# Replacing Cosets

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

> Give an example of a non-abelian group $G$ containing a proper normal subgroup $N$ such that $G/N$ is abelian.

Take $G = D_{2n}$ and consider $\langle r \rangle$ (subgroup of rotations). I already proved that $\langle r \rangle$ is normal, so that we can sensibly speak of $D_{2n}/ \langle r \rangle$ as a quotient group. Now, I am trying to show that this quotient group is abelian. My proof relies on whether $xN = yN$ whenever $x,y \in N$. I realize this is simple, but I already asked a simple question today, thinking I was right about the answer, and I ended being wrong---so I don't want to do that again! I believe this would be a proof: $xN = N = yN$.

Is this right?

Comment: $N$ being a subgroup, meaning it's a group itself, means it's closed under the group operation. If $xN:=\{xn\mid n\in N\}$, then this is certainly a subset of $N$ if $x\in N$, by closure. It's all of $N$ because $x(x^{-1}n)=n\in N$, and $x^{-1}\in N$ again due to the group axioms.

Comment: This is not directly your question, but you could also show that $G/N$ is abelian because $|G/N| = 2$.

Comment: Only two elements on this quotient group. I suppose it should make it Abelian.

Comment: @OwenSizemore Ah, yes! Very good! Although this problem comes before any mention of the index, I am taking note of this solution for future reference. But for now I will just use my idea of replacing cosets when explicitly showing that the quotient is an abelian group.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works because:

- Every subgroup of index $2$ is normal.
- Every group of order $2$ is abelian.

Another example that works for the same reason is $G=S_n$ and $N=A_n$.